# How to use session variable time to show quiz timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

currently I am working on a online quiz platform and I want to show a quiz timer.first I use javascript to show timer but problem is that when user refresh a page or goes back the quiz timer start again form start so I want to use session variable time to show quiz timer. and I set this session variable when user start the quiz. but my code is not working properly. here is my code:

```html
`<?php
include_once 'dbConnection.php';
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['email']))){
header("location:login.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 
 <script>
  // timer will start when document is loaded 
  $(document).ready( function () { 
  startTest();
  });
  var si;
  function timer(){
      <?php $_SESSION['time']-= 1000; ?>
      var count="<?php  echo $_SESSION['time'];  ?>";
      var min = Math.floor(count / (60 * 1000));
      var sec = Math.floor((count - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);
      min = (min < 10)?'0'+min:min;
      sec = (sec < 10)?'0'+sec:sec;   
      if (count <= 0){
        document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML ="Time Up";
        clearInterval(si);
       // submit my quiz.
      } 
      else {
        document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML = "00:" + min + ":" + sec;
      }
    } 
    function startTest(){
      si = setInterval( "timer()", 1000);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="duration" >show time</p>

</body>
</html>`
```

this code is giving some unexpected error or doesn't work properly.

Comment: put this <?php $_SESSION['time']-= 1000; ?> outside of script tag

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes if its an integer

```
 var count=<?php  echo $_SESSION['time'];  ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your description is that you need time duration from server side. so that if any one refresh the browser don't restart the timer from the beginning . 
You need to calculate the time duration on server side. That can be achieved by using ajax call.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['start_time'] = time();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  // timer will start when document is loaded 
  $(document).ready( function () { 
    setInterval(() => {
        $.ajax({
            url:"timer.php",  //path to your file
            success:function(data) {
               // do your code here
               $('#duration').text(data);

            }
        }); 
    }, 1000);

  });

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="duration" >show time</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Create new php file for calculating time timer.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$start_time = $_SESSION['start_time']; // start time;
$from_time =  time(); // current time;


    $minutes = round(abs($start_time - $from_time) / 60);
    $seconds = abs($to_time - $from_time) % 60;

    echo "$minutes minutes & $seconds seconds";

?>
```

Comment: $_SESSION['start_time'] = time(); remove this. because this will reset the session.. use according to your requirement..